# ¿Cómo saber en qué casos no sirve mi código?

Tags: c++

Este es un codigo planteado para hallar el numero de digitos que existe en una cadena numérica, formada por los enteros menores a un entero N ingresado. Por ejemplo 5 forma la cadena 12345 y tiene 5 digitos. La entrada consiste en cualquier entero positivo.
El intento de solucion fue el siguiente

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 
int main(){
int n; 
cin >> n;

int digitos = 0;
int iteracion = 1;
int longitud = 1;

if(n<10){
digitos += n;
}

if(n>=10 && n<100){
digitos += 9+(n-9)*2;
}

if (n>=100){
for (int i= n; i >= 10; i /= 10,iteracion *= 10,++longitud){

digitos += ((9 * iteracion) * longitud);
}digitos += (((n % iteracion) + 1) * longitud);
}

cout << digitos <<endl;

return 0;
}
```

No obstante, un programa me dice que no funciona para ciertos casos. Pero no sé para qué casos no funciona y qué error podría existir en el código. ¿Qué caso podría fallar?

Answer (score 1):

> No obstante, un programa me dice que no funciona para ciertos casos.

Utilizas el tipo `int` para almacenar la secuencia. Este tipo ocupa, a lo sumo, 32 bits. Teniendo en cuenta que es un tipo con signo (un bit lo consume la gestión del signo), te quedan 31 bits para almacenar la secuencia.

Como `2^31 = 2.147.483.648`, cualquier secuencia cuyo resultado de un número superior al mismo provocará que el programa funcione erráticamente.

Así pues, dado que tu programa genera secuencias tipo: `12345...`, funcionará incorrectamente cuando `N>10`.

Ahora bien, como `int` también puede ocupar 16 bits (los tipos en C++ son dependientes de la arquitectura del sistema), el programa puede llegar a fallar con valores inferiores de `N` (este último caso dejo que lo calcules tu).

El caso, para evitar esta limitación tendrías que cambiár `digitos` para que sea de tipo `std::string`. De esta forma podrás almacenar una secuencia prácticamente infinita sin problemas. Eso sí, tendrás que convertir los números a cadena de caracteres, pero eso no suele suele suponer un problema hoy en día:

```
std::string texto = std::to_string(123456);
std::cout << texto;
```

Answer (score -1):

El siguiente codigo cuenta e imprime los numeros que componen los numeros menores a un entero tecleado por el usuario.

```
#include <iostream>
#include using namespace std; 

int main(){
int numero_ingresado; 
cin >> numero_ingresado;

int numero_digitos= 0;
if (bumero_ingresado<0)
{
//mencionar alerta sobre negativos
}

for (int i= 0; i <= numero_ingresado;i++){
numero_digitos +=1;
cout <<i;// algo asi
}
cout << numero_digitos <<endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: que hace ese código que publicaste?

Comment: ingorando los errores de sintaxis ya que no tengo un editor a mano, hace lo necesita el usuario, datos mas datos menos, pero no deberia haber los errores que inquietan al que hace tiene dudas

Comment: entonces por favor añade una explicación para mejorar tu respuesta, ya que solo colocar código se considera de baja calidad

Comment: Al menos que los numeros de 2 o mas digitos tambien haya que iterarlos entonces requiere de un metodo mas, ahorita lo genero...

Comment: ¿Y como uso el codigo para determinar en que casos no sirven? Además, tu codigo no sirve del todo porque incluye el 0, el cual no deberia estar. También imprime un numero mas que el entero formador de la lista

Comment: Que no tengas editor a mano no es excusa hoy en día. Hay varios compiladores online que premiten compilar y probar códigos sencillos... por ejemplo https://wandbox.org/

Comment: Gracias por la observacion.